# Error starting mariaDB on docker-compose build

Tags: docker, mariadb

After do a images rm, volumes rm and docker prune i got this error starting mariaDB on with docker-compose

This is the db compose part (yml):

```
    mariaDB:
    image: 'mariadb:latest'
    environment:
        - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root_password
```

The error log:

mariaDB_1                      | 2022-05-27 20:14:42+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MariaDB Server 1:10.8.3+maria~jammy started.

mariaDB_1                      | 2022-05-27 20:14:42+00:00 [ERROR] [Entrypoint]:

mariadbd failed while attempting to check config

mariaDB_1                      |        command was: mariadbd --verbose --help --log-bin-index=/tmp/tmp.JMRNT5ajM6

mariaDB_1                      |        Can't initialize timers
services_mariaDB_1 exited with code 1

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have any volumes? Is that the full configuration for MariaDB?

Comment: No, I haven´t. This is the full configuration. Is running good until now

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Same problem here with latest docker container of MariaDB and the latest tag. Pinning to 10.8.2 (mariadb:10.8.2) in docker-compose fixes this issue.db:

This is my new image line and with 10.8.2 it keeps working. In the mariadb issue tracker is already a discussion going so they are working on this.

image: mariadb:10.8.2

Comment: Finally I rearmed a new VM instance, but thank's for the info. I try to use this version the next time

Comment: Worked for me. I used 10.7 as suggested below.

Comment: The real issue for me was that no further explanation appears in the logs, so it's not clear how to debug it. After pinning to `10.8.2` the container was starting up with a different error message; I could then run `mysql-upgrade` and the issue was gone.

Answer (score 13):

Dekyi unfortunately left something important out: 10.8.2 is technically not production safe. 10.8.2 is a release candidate, 10.8.3 is the only general availability version in the 10.8 series. 10.8.2 is OK for testing and *probably* OK enough for production, but there were still a handful of bugfixes between 10.8.2 and 10.8.2. If you need guaranteed stability, stay on 10.7 (10.7.4 is the latest stable) until you can upgrade docker (see below).

Now on to the issue - more info is here: https://github.com/MariaDB/mariadb-docker/issues/434. It seems like the issue is that the 10.8.3 uses Debian Jammy as the base image, rather than Focal, and there are some issues running Jammy stuff on older versions of docker. Per a commenter on GH, docker version 20.10.10+ is required, so run `docker --version` and see what you are running.

The best solution is to upgrade Docker. If you can't do that, there's the `10.8-focal` tag which currently points to 10.8.2 - see comments above before using that though. [There are also some flags that might make 10.8.3 start successfully](https://github.com/MariaDB/mariadb-docker/issues/434#issuecomment-1136603512), you'd have to override the entrypoint.

If all else fails, just stick on 10.7 until you can upgrade docker, or until they release a 10.8.3-focal image (should be coming, Docker just takes a while to update official images).

Edit: here is a writeup on the root cause of the issue, which includes some other possible workarounds https://medium.com/nttlabs/ubuntu-21-10-and-fedora-35-do-not-work-on-docker-20-10-9-1cd439d9921

Comment: This is useful information, but is it relevant? How do you know? It does not really help us who have the same problem and who may be on completely different software versions. This question will still be here five years from now.

Comment: @reinierpost I am unsure what point you are making. How do I know what? I consider it relevant as I provide multiple possible resolutions to the question asked, with explanations and citations. Five years from now this exact version-specific question won't be relevant, because MariaDB will be 5 versions past 10.8, and docker <20 is already currently EOL.

Comment: Docker version 20.10.17, build 100c701, mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.8.3-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper - WORK FINE! Thank you1!